# Singleton and Prototype in one Container

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If there are two bean, and the bean b1 the scope is singleton, bean b2 the scope is prototype.In this case if the container is started then how many beans are created and to which scope it will go.

Answer (score 0):

Two beans shall be created. One singleton and the other prototype.
If you are talking about two beans of same class, then also the scenario is same.

When you shall autowire the beans you would have to provide a qualifier attribute.

eg:

```
<bean id="a" class="package.classname" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="b" class="package.classname" scope="singleton" />
```

During autowiring:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(id="a")
public package.classname instance1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier(id="b")
public package.classname instance2;
```